# mixture problem solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

suppose we are given following problem.

A tank contains 50 gallons of a solution composed of 90% water and 10% alcohol.
A second solution containing 50% water and 50% alcohol is added to the tank at
the rate of 4 gallons per minute. As the second solution is being added, the tank
is being drained at the rate of 5 gallons per minute. Assuming
the solution in the tank is stirred constantly, how much alcohol is in the tank after  10 minutes?
i guessed that it is related  with differential equation,also i know that at time  t=0,in tank there is 45 gallons water and 5 gallons  alcohol,because  per minute  4 gallons is added ,it means that  2 gallons water and 2  gallons  alcohol is added so it  one minute 7  gallons  alcohol is in tank yes?and also because  5 gallons   drained per minute ,we must substract 2.5 -2.5 each  water and  alcohol yes?please help me  how  to define  how much alcohol will be in 10 minutes.

Comment: This problem *with solution* can be found [here](http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/calculus_early/3e/shared/chapter15/clc7eap1502.pdf) , example 4 of section 15.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V(t)=total volume of water
g(t)=volume of alcohol

$V=(4-5)t+50$

$\frac{dg}{dt}=2-5\frac{g}{v}$

use integrating factor method:

$I=e^{\int\frac{5}{-t+50}}=(50-t)^{-5}$

$Ig(t)=\int2(50-t)^{-5}=)=(\frac{1}{2}(t-50)^{-4}+C$

$g(t)=(\frac{1}{2}(t-50)+C(50-t)^{5}$

Comment: thanks @Angela Richardson and one more question,if instead of  alcohol,we are interested in water then?

Comment: Amount of water=total volume - amount of alcohol. Total volume=50-t.

Comment: I think that $V(t)=50-t$ is the total volume of the *water and alcohol solution*.

Comment: +1, Typos: $$I=e^{\int\frac{5}{-t+50}dt}=(50-t)^{-5}$$

$$Ig(t)=\int2(50-t)^{-5}dt=\frac{1}{2}(t-50)^{-4}+C$$

$$g(t)=\frac{1}{2}(50-t)+C(50-t)^{5}.$$